# Removing the "about:blank" text from a new tab

Tags: macos, google-chrome

In one of my Google Chrome profiles, opening a new tab displays the text `about:blank` in it. This has become increasingly annoying because my muscle memory is such that I start typing the URL `foo.com` immediately after opening a new tab, and with this pre-filled text, it ends up being `about:blankfoo.com`.

[image: screenshot of a new tab]

From a quick comparison of the preferences between this profile and another one (where this doesn't happen), I couldn't find anything that was obviously off, but perhaps I am not looking in the right place.

Is there a way to remove this pre-filled text from a new tab?

Comment: @techie007 he doesn't want to make the new tab totally blank, he wants that the NTP doesn't display the `about:blank` page.

Comment: @Braiam From the linked question: "Is there a way to either clear about:blank entirely or select all the text, so I can start typing straight away and not have to CMD/CTRL + A and backspace/delete?" the title on it is just crappy. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Type `chrome://settings/` in the address bar, "On startup" section is very likely you have "Open a specific page or set of pages. Change it to "Open the New Tab page".

[image]

If you want to do thing manually, you can modify the `Preferences` file in the Default directory of Chrome/ium and look for this entry:

```
"new_tab_url": "{google:baseURL}_/chrome/newtab?{google:RLZ}{google:instantExtendedEnabledParameter}{google:ntpIsThemedParameter}ie={inputEncoding}",
```

yours most likely say:

```
"new_tab_url": "about:blank",
```

Just replace it with something you like.

Comment: No, I have it set to "Open the New Tab page"...

Comment: Nope. It doesn't say "about:blank". I think it might be caused by a plugin. Will investigate...

Comment: Yeah, that's another annoying possibility.